# Resource in .Net Standard project is not added to DLL

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-standard, .net-standard-2.0

A resource added to a .NET standard project does not get compiled into the DLL.

I'm porting a .NET Framework project to .NET Standard. My original project has some resources, marked as "Build Action : Resource" which are being consumed by other assemblies.

The .NET Standard project file.

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup> *** not sure why this is added by VS2019 **
    <None Remove="Resources\ErrorLarge.png" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="Resources\ErrorLarge.png" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

DLL content and size does not change with "Build Action" property changed from "None" to "Resource". Naturally my consumer assemblies will return a `IOException: Cannot locate resource 'resources/errorlarge.png'.` error.

VS2019 - 16.2.4

Comment: Wrong name.  Run ildasm.exe on the generated assembly and ensure you see the `.mresource` in the manifest.  Correct the client code to use the name you see back for the resource.

Comment: @HansPassant - Thanks but I don't think so. I've checked with a JustDecompile prior and there was no resources in the DLL. To confirm, I've added a large image and rebuilt but the file size and content didn't change.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want `EmbeddedResource` in your CSProj file rather than `Resource`.

This seems [useful at describing adding & reading them](https://codeopinion.com/asp-net-core-csproj-embedded-resources/).

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately a ```BuildAction:Embedded Resource``` can't be consumed via Pack URIs. They must be ```BuildAction:Resources``` as in our .NET Framework assembly which is being ported.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem right now in a .Net 7 project. Apparently, resources are only compiled into the DLL in a WPF project.

I'd love to have some more information on that, but the line that got it to work, was the following in the csproj file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>disable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <OutputPath>..\bin</OutputPath>
    <GenerateDocumentationFile>True</GenerateDocumentationFile>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>False</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
    <IsPackable>False</IsPackable>

    // this line here
    <UseWPF>True</UseWPF>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Setting the project to use WPF also required me to specify a platform for the target framework, so I changed the target from `net7.0` to `net7.0-windows`